# Winding numbers and complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework question asking me to show that for $P(z) = z^6 - 5z^4 + 10$:
A) There are no roots of $P(z)$ in $|z| < 1$.
B) There are four roots of $P(z)$ in $|z| < 2$.
C) There are six roots of $P(z)$ in $|z| < 3$.

From what I understand, this question is simply asking me to find the winding numbers of P with respect to these three curves.

For part A, I got $\Delta_{c_1} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{6ie^{6it}-20ie^{4it}}{e^{6it}-5e^{4it}+10} dt$ = 0

But when I tried the same process for part B, I ended up getting 2. This makes me believe I've done something wrong in part A. What is my mistake?

To obtain my integrand in part A, I parameterized $|z|<1$ as $e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t < 2pi$. Then, I found $P'(z(t)) = 6ie^{6it}-20ie^{4it}$ and $P(z(t) =e^{6it}-5e^{4it}+10$. Since the formula for a contour integral is $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int \frac{P'(z(t))}{P(z(t))}dt$, I simply plugged my values for $P'(z(t))$ and $P(z(t))$ in and evaluated the integral with Mathematica.

Comment: It might be easier to use Rouché‘s theorem.

Comment: And why do you think that your result for A is wrong if you computed the correct winding number zero? You should check your calculation for B.

Comment: The question *“What is my mistake?”* cannot be answered without seeing your exact calculations.

Comment: You have $P'(z(t)) = 6e^{5it} -20e^{3it}$. However, the correct contour integral is $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int \frac{P'(z(t))}{P(z(t))}z'(t)dt$ which gives in fact your formula for $\Delta_{c_1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't come back to this last night. I fell asleep about 20 minutes after I asked it. You made me realize that I was being stupid and had actually written down the wrong integral for part B. Thank you for your help everybody. @PaulFrost

Answer (score 2):

On $|z|=1$ we have $|z^{6}-5z^{4}| <10$ Hence, by Rouche's Theorem $z^{6}-5z^{4}+10$ and $10$ have the same number of zeros in $|z|<1$. This proves the first part. Similarly, on $|z|=2$ we have $|z^{6}+10| <5|z|^{4}$ and hence $z^{6}-5z^{4}+10$ and $5z^{4}$ have the same number of zeros in $|z|<2$. Finally on $|z|=3$ we have $|10-5z^{4}| <|z^{6}|$ and hence $z^{6}-5z^{4}+10$ and $z^{6}$ have the same number of zeros in $|z|<3$.